# cronjob to store home-ip

Tags: networking, apache2, cron

I'm working out a cronjob to store my current ip (home-server) on my external VPS server in a database.
I can now use the ip to connect to my home server without using DynDNS.
(OK, probably you think why not just use DynDNS, cause I don't feel safe about someone having my ip in his database every time it changes.)

Is there any possible way to execute a php file periodically that is on my VPS server to determinate my current ip at home and then store it in a DB?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use either `wget` or `curl` for this. A crontab entry like this on your home system will do the trick (updating every 30 minutes):

```
*/30 * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://your.server.com/ip-logger.php  >/tmp/last-ip.log
```

Use `crontab -e` to open an editor with your crontab entries, and add that line at the end. This will discard any output sent by the ip logger server-side script, and log the last console output in `/tmp/last-ip.log`, in case you need to debug something.

Server-side, your PHP script needs to look at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and log that into your database. How to do this is outside the scope of this reply :)